# converting into a valid URL NodeJs

Tags: node.js

Currently working on facebook chatbot i need help on how can i convert the image url into a valid url.

**Image url:** https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fv%2Ft1.15752-9%2F214908621_564453328293921_3260538045400412837_n.png%3F_nc_cat%3D108%26ccb%3D1-3%26_nc_sid%3D58c789%26_nc_ohc%3DW2cGUFX8KXcAX_GqVUx%26_nc_ad%3Dz-m%26_nc_cid%3D0%26_nc_ht%3Dscontent.xx%26oh%3D5a33ef0279fb27a685ed623cf69ec08c%26oe%3D60FCC37B

**convert it to this:** https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/214908621_564453328293921_3260538045400412837_n.png?_nc_cat=108&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=58c789&_nc_ohc=W2cGUFX8KXcAX_GqVUx&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=5a33ef0279fb27a685ed623cf69ec08c&oe=60FCC37B

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try  `decodeURIComponent`?

Comment: This works! Thank you very much sir @JoachimIsaksson